# C# Sudoku (Unity) endless loop

Tags: c#, loops, sudoku

When I press start game button in unity, Unity screen freeze and a constantly increasing amount of ram.
(I think endless loop) Can anyone help with the error in my code? (No debug) Thank you very much. :) I have a prefabs and prefabs have a Image and Text. ( and don't wory I do to inject code in prefabs and canvas.)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grid2 : MonoBehaviour
{
public int columns = 0;
public int rows = 0;
public float every_square_offset = 0.0f;
public GameObject grid_square;
public UnityEngine.Vector2 start_position = new UnityEngine.Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);

private List<GameObject> grid_squares_ = new List<GameObject>();

void Start()
{
    if (grid_square.GetComponent<GridSquare>() == null)
        Debug.LogError("grid_square object need to have GridSquare script attached!");

        CreateGrid();
        SetGridNumbers();
}

private void CreateGrid()
{
    SpawnGridSquares();
    SetSquarePosition();
}

private void SpawnGridSquares()
{
    //0, 1,3,4,5,6
    //7,8,9,10 ...

    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < columns; columns++)
        {
            grid_squares_.Add(Instantiate(grid_square) as GameObject);
            grid_squares_[grid_squares_.Count - 1].transform.parent = this.transform; // instantiate this game object as a child of the object holding this script.
        }
    }
}

private void SetSquarePosition()
{
    var square_rect = grid_squares_[0].GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    UnityEngine.Vector2 offset = new UnityEngine.Vector2();
    offset.x = square_rect.rect.width * square_rect.transform.localScale.x + every_square_offset;
    offset.y = square_rect.rect.height * square_rect.transform.localScale.y + every_square_offset;

    int column_number = 0;
    int row_number = 0;

    foreach (GameObject square in grid_squares_)
    {
        if(column_number + 1 > columns) 
        {
            row_number++;
            column_number = 0;
        }

        var pos_x_offset = offset.x * column_number;
        var pos_y_offset = offset.y * row_number;
        square.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new UnityEngine.Vector3(start_position.x + pos_x_offset, start_position.y - pos_y_offset);
        column_number++;
    }
}
private void SetGridNumbers()
{
    foreach(var square in grid_squares_)
    {
        square.GetComponent<GridSquare>().SetNumber(Random.Range(0, 10));
    }
}
```

}

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GridSquare : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject number_text;
private int number_ = 0;
public void DisplayText()
{
    if (number_ <= 0)
        number_text.GetComponent<Text>().text = " ";

    else
        number_text.GetComponent<Text>().text = number_.ToString();
}

public void SetNumber(int number)
{
    number_ = number;
}
}
```

Comment: Create a StreamWriter and write debug info to the stream writer to determine where you are having issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int column = 0; column < columns; columns++)
```

You're incrementing the upper boundary, not the counter.

This should be:

```
for(int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
```

You could have easily found this bug by stepping through the code. Please refer to [the Unity manual on debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) for more information.

Comment: Oh my eyes , thank you for solving my problem. The problem has been fixed and creates the squares.